# How to find the minimum of the grand canonical potential?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I have tried to solve the following problem:

If I have an open system in contact with a thermostat at temperature $T$ and a reservoir of particles with chemical potential $\mu$, how can I show that the grand potential $\Omega=E-TS-\mu N$ reaches a minimum when the grand canonical distribution is fulfilled? And what would be the value of that minimum?

Comment: Aside from the symbols being a little strange, it's not that the potential reaches a minimum, it's that the number of microstates (typically called $\Omega$, not the $\Omega$ you have used) is at a maximum with respect to the $NVE$ ensemble.
On a side note, how has the username physics never been taken before?

Comment: Names are not unique @MichaelBurt

Comment: Well that's good to know. Haha

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!